# ubuntu litespeed php7.0 got a weird php.ini path

Tags: php, ubuntu, caching, composer-php, litespeed

Ubuntu 16.04.2
LSPHP7.0

```
 wget -O - http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/enable_lst_debain_repo.sh | bash
 apt install -y lsphp70
```

Then I added `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/bin` to $PATH and made a symlink for `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/bin/php7.0` to `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/bin/php`. This way I can run php in terminal as cli version.

```
 apt install composer
 composer require geoip2/geoip2:~2.0
```

I got an error said `the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.`

And also it said

```
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

But when I run `php -i | grep php.ini` it shows the ini is not `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` but `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/etc/php/7.0/litespeed/php.ini`

Further more, I run `php --ini`, it shows:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/litespeed/
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/etc/php/7.0/litespeed/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/curl.ini,
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/imap.ini,
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/json.ini,
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini,
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini,
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70//etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
```

How can php cli get `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` as its php config file? Anyone gives a clue? thanks.

Comment: Wired or Weird?

Comment: Might be better to ask in http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for correcting typo. Not sure if should ask there as its a php.ini issue

Comment: The default config path is set during php compilation, so you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu normally installs system default php(currently php7.0) to /usr/bin/php

Composer will normally call the PHP defined in $PATH, usually /usr/bin/php.

The Error "the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system" means Ubuntu system default php7.0 curl is missing. To resolve:
   `apt-get install php7.0-curl`
So far, it should resolve your problem already.

LiteSpeed Web Server normally use LiteSpeed API to communicate with PHP engine, which is faster than other APIs. In LiteSpeed Ubuntu/Debian repo, it provides different versions of lsphp, which will be at different location other than system default location, normally at /usr/local/lsws/lsphpxx/bin/.

Composer will normally use system default php location as explain above. If you want to overwrite PHP path to use lsphp70 php binary, you will need to add this path to the beginning of $PATH.

`export PATH="/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/bin/:$PATH"`

This way, when you run:

`which php`

System should use the php found first in the PATH, which is   `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/bin/php`

In this case, when you see similar php-curl missing error message, you should run:
   `apt-get install lsphp70-curl`
to fix the problem.

To make the new PATH permanently, you can edit ~/.profile or .bashrc, or any other similar way, which is beyond the discussion of this topic.